# Plesk webmail error. Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php

Привет всем!

Plesk version 9.5.4. Я логинюсь в почту где около 8500 писем общим объёмом 3.3 Гб. Но вместо списка писем в папке "Входящие" psa-horde показывает ошибку как на скриншоте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думал что привышен лимит допустимой памяти в mod_php у apache, но в error log apache нет сообщения о такой ошибке. Но есть ошибка в логе psa-horde:

> HORDE [error] [imp] Unable to retrieve quota [pid 31971 on line 1009
>   of "/usr/share/psa-horde/imp/lib/IMP.php"]

Ок, давайте глянем что на той строке:

```
$quota = $quotaDriver->getQuota();
if (is_a($quota, 'PEAR_Error')) {
Horde::logMessage($quota, __FILE__, __LINE__, PEAR_LOG_ERR);
return false;
}
```

В свою очередь, метод getQuota() используется из Quota.php

```
function getQuota()
{
return array('usage' => 0, 'limit' => 0);
}
```

Где какой лимит увеличить чтобы письма отобразились все и без этой ошибки?
Нагуглил вариант с тем что нужно поставить в настройках веб интерфейса почта порядок сортировки по времени получения писем но это не помогло, так и стояло.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что второй кусок кода не имеет никакого отношения к первому. В первом у вас переменная `$quota` задается классом PEAR_Error(который, кстати, deprecated). Функция приведенная ниже никак не может его вернуть, от слова вообще.

Comment: Тут дело не в коде, он просто для справки, тут дело в большом ящике с письмами думаю, который не укладывается в какой-то лимит. Остальные ящики в которых не так много писем работают нормально.

Comment: Если с php'шным memory_limit все в порядке, то вы можете упираться в более низкоуровневый лимит по памяти на сервере для юзера. Если вы админ, посмотрите ```ulimit -a``` от пользователя, от которого работает plesk, если не админ - обращайтесь в поддержку сервера.